# ошибка shape mismatch

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy, matplotlib

у меня есть массив который представляет из себя

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] 
... 
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

между нулями там еще много чисел. Когда я подаю этот массив в свой код то сталкиваюсь с ошибкой: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.
вот код который я использую:

```
z = b_line #b_line представляет из себя массив указанный выше
x = np.outer(np.linspace(0, len(z), len(z[0])), np.ones(len(z[0])))
y = x.copy().T # transpose
z = np.array(z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих разборок, могу предложить  следующий, классический вариант, который работает для  произвольных матриц

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
b_line=[
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
]
z = b_line #b_line представляет из себя массив указанный выше
x=np.linspace(0, len(z), len(z[0]))
y=np.linspace(0, len(z[0]),len(z))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.array(z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, z)
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.show()
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это гениально

Comment: а есть ли возможность оптимизировать график? а то я когда его вращаю это происходит с фпс наверно 5 в секунду, причем это не зависит от кол-ва точек на нем

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы понимаете под словосочетанием "оптимизировать график"? Для небольших графиков, разумеется, вращение будет обрабатываться быстрее, для очень больших -  медленнее.  Что такое оптимизация для этого случая? Ну, уменьшите количество точек, предварительно усреднив их значения. Это уже решать вам -  что вам важнее, скорость отображения или точность воспроизведения.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не приводите воспроизводимый фрагмент кода?
Нам остается только догадываться, что вы там написали или забыли написать.

Поскольку ваш код вы от нас скрыли, то есть сильное подозрение, что вы забыли вставить

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Вот так ваш код выглядит у меня:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
b_line=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
z = b_line #b_line представляет из себя массив указанный выше
x = np.outer(np.linspace(0, len(z), len(z[0])), np.ones(len(z[0])))
y = x.copy().T # transpose
z = np.array(z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,edgecolor='none',cmap='viridis')
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.show()
```

И вот так выглядит результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, все работает.

Comment: к сожалению все библиотеки я подключил правильно, фрагмент кода я не могу привести потому что это для диплома и я не хочу пролететь с антиплагиатом.Тут скорее ошибка с самим массивом, но весь код и файлы которые там открываются могу скинуть только на почту

Comment: Спасибо, не надо. Значит, выяснили, что код рабочий. Теперь смотрите, что не так с данными. Ничего сверхсложного в этом нет.  Предположу, что ваша матрица b_line - не квадратная. По крайней мере, ваша ошибка у меня возникает именно в таком случае.

Comment: А как это можно исправить? ведь я беру эти данные из другого фала, в котором ничего нельзя редактировать.

Comment: См. мой ответ ниже.